# Could a reference like "as I said before" sound odd when I actually wrote it?

Tags: style

I am writing a long explanation, and in many points I have either to recall something I wrote earlier or note that something will be explained later. I have the sensation that referring to the writing is a bit cold, so instead of putting "as I wrote before" I put "as I said before". I also wrote "I'll talk about it later". So the explanation is written as if it were spoken. Will it sound odd to the reader?

Comment: Are you writing an email?

Comment: @NofP No, actually I don't know how it will be used. As of now it's a document with several chapters. But a strict professional style is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is that is kind of depends on what you are writing about.

If it is a personal essay, then it can sound pretty normal, because the voice of  that kind of piece is nearly always direct address.

But, if you were relating writing a book report or topic paper, using direct address and breaking the 4th wall is usually considered bad form. But, if your paper or report autobiography is about your personal experiences, such as if you were the first person on Mars, containing lots of details about the experience, then it might work.  It is a function of the tone of the piece.

If it was the first time in the piece you engaged in that kind of direct address, then I suspect it would read weird.  But, if your piece regularly made use of breaking the 4th wall, and having the narrator directly address the reader in a folksy and down to earth manner, then I doubt it would read badly at all.

It might read like many answers on writing@se. As I said before, it depends on the form and content the of piece.